# How to Change the IP Address List Order returned by gethostbyname?

Tags: windows, networking, ipv4, gethostbyname

I've an application which calls gethostbyname and displays the first IP address in the h_addr_list. On machine which has VMware installed on it and has multiple virtual adapters, my application always returns the IP address of one of the **virtual adapters.** I always want my application to give me the IP address of **physical adapter.**

Therefore I want to reorder my virtual adapters in such a way that the IP address of physical adapter shall be first in the list. I tried all the suggestions in -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171320

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564/en-us#appliesto

None of them worked. I restarted my system after making changes too. Is there any other way to change the order of network adapters? Assuming there isn't, how can I ensure through my code that I always get the IP address of my physical adapter?

My OS is windows 8. Here is my ipconfig /all output -

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Win8x64D3b
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : NESSINBLR.COM

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : NESSINBLR.COM
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connec
tion
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-FE-E7-00-A6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bc7c:6cf5:e8ed:c874%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.82.152(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, June 19, 2013 2:55:44 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, June 21, 2013 2:55:38 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.80.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.116.52
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251662334
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-3D-50-E5-00-0F-FE-E7-00-A6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.82.152
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 172.26.82.152
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d59f:e785:bc67:74c4%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251678806
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-3D-50-E5-00-0F-FE-E7-00-A6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3d00:a19f:32b5:5c52%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268456022
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-3D-50-E5-00-0F-FE-E7-00-A6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A80B07CA-01EF-411D-BB81-A4E2F06D588B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.NESSINBLR.COM:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : NESSINBLR.COM
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8D6220B3-8F39-4514-8C4E-C79D8263C2B8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

My application always returns 192.168.5.1 instead of 172.26.82.152

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something similar. This doesn't totally answer your question, but this is what I have.

```
remoteHost = gethostbyname(ac);
int i = 0;
if (remoteHost->h_addrtype == AF_INET)
{
    //while (remoteHost->h_addr_list[i] != 0) 
    //{
    //  addr.s_addr = *(u_long *) remoteHost->h_addr_list[i++];
    //}
    addr.s_addr = *(u_long *) remoteHost->h_addr_list[0];
}
```

I've commented out the while loop. That part just keeps looping over the list of adapters, eventually stopping on the last one (which in our case, is the VMware adapters).

Using the h_addr_list[0] gives my physical adapter. However, I'm not sure how the order is actually determined, or how I can tell which is physical, and which is virtual.

Hope that helps a little.